# All of the elements change on Click, not just the targeted one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just playing with some basic Jquery and something strange is happening. I have two elements on the page.. an h1 heading, and a generic link. When I click the link I would like the text to change to "This text has now changed", and it does, but then either the button disappears and a new h1 is created with the same "this text has not changed" text, or the button itself turns into the h1. I'm not sure, but here's my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>This element should change.<h1>


        <a href="#" class="myLink">Click Me</a><br>


    </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".myLink").click(function() {  // this is a convenience method that targets the same elements above just in a quicker fashion.
            $("h1").html("This text has now changed.");
     });

});
```

Picture Before the click:

[image]

Picture After:

[image]

Also, when I added the fade out method everything disappears once again, not just the targeted "h1" element.

Any advice is greatly appreciated as always. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two opening `<h1>` tags (the second one is missing a `/`.)

```
<h1>This element should change.<h1>
                                ^here
```

Comment: happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have two *start* tags. EG:

```
<h1>Heading 1<h1>
```

Try changing the second tag to an end tag. EG:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
              ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Your h1 tag is not closed. You have 2 opening  tags, and by default, your link is contained by the second opening tag so it's changing that html